# How to proof a sigma algebra is equal to the union of two given subsets?

Tags: measure-theory

EDIT: I edited it after user469053s correction

I'm doing a homework exercise about measure theory and can't figure out how to proof the following: Let $(X,A)$ be a measurable space, $g \subset A$ a generator of A and $S \in A$. Proof the following: \begin{equation}
A = \{B \cup C : B \in \sigma(g \cap S), C \in \sigma(g \cap S^c) \}
\end{equation}
For one direction I have what I believe to be a correct proof, but I don't see how I can proof that $A \subset \{B \cup C : B \in \sigma(g \cap S), C \in \sigma(g \cap S^c) \}$. A random element $X \in A$ I can write as: $X = (X \cap S) \cup (X \cap S^c)$, but I don't know how to proof they are in their respective sigma algebras.

(For the other direction I have that $(g \cap S), (g \cap S^c) \subset g$, so we know that the following holds: $\sigma(g \cap S), \sigma(g \cap S^c) \subset \sigma(g) = A$. Because a sigma algebra is closed under union, this also means: $\{B \cup C : B \in \sigma(g \cap S), C \in \sigma(g \cap S^c) \} \subset \sigma(g) = A$.)

Comment: Equality is false even when $g=A$.

Comment: You don't mean $\sigma(g\cap S)\cup \sigma(g\cap S^C)$. You mean $$\{B\cup C:B\in \sigma(g\cap S), C\in \sigma(g\cap S^C)\}.$$

Comment: You're right, I modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note on notation: $g\cap S$ denotes $\{B\cap S:B\in g\}$.

Let $L$ denote the set of $B\in A$ such that $B\cap S\in \sigma(g\cap S)$.

1. $X\cap S=S\in \sigma(g\cap S)$.
2. For $(B_i)_{i=1}^\infty\subset L$, $\Bigl(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i\Bigr)\cap S=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (B_i\cap S)\in \sigma(g\cap S)$.
3. $(X\setminus B)\cap S=S\setminus B=S\setminus (S\cap B)\in \sigma(g\cap S)$.

So $L$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. It clearly contains $g$, since for any $B\in g$, $B\cap S\in g\cap S\subset \sigma(g\cap S)$. So $L$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $A$ containing $g$, so it also contains $A$. Therefore $B\cap S\in \sigma(g\cap S)$ for any $B\in A$. The same argument yields that $B\cap S^C\in \sigma(g\cap S^C)$ for any $B\in A$. So for any $B\in A$, we have $$B=(B\cap S)\cup (B\cap S^C)\in \{C\cup C':C\in \sigma(g\cap S),C'\in \sigma(g\cap S^C)\}.$$

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot!